# How to Insert a Value That Might Contain an Apostrophe

Tags: php, sql

How would I go about writing a SQL statement that would insert values that **might** contain an apostrophe (for example one person's last name was Conner and another's was O'Conner)? After some searching, I found examples using a double apostrophe (`O''Conner example`) but each example had the string hard coded in the the `INSERT`. I haven't run across any examples where the value may or may not contain an apostrophe.

My simple statement doesn't have any issues when no apostrophe is used but when one is it fails. I know I could replace the apostrophe using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) but, obviously, that would cause the O'Conner example to be displayed as OConner.

Here is a shorthand version, just for an example:

**page1.php**

```
// PHP
include_once('phpdata.php');
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

    // SQL connection
    $insert = doInsert($firstname, $lastname);
    // Execute statement using odbc_exec, etc.
}

// HTML
<input type="text" class="required" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
<input type="text" class="required" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
```

**phpdata.php**

```
function doInsert($firstname, $lastname) {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO mytable (firstname, lastname)
                VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname')";
    return $insert;
}
```

Comment: Consider using [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: I accidentally left out the last closed quote in the INSERT but keep getting an error when I try to edit the post. Not sure why I can't edit it.

Comment: There's probably hundreds of questions like this by now on Stack Overflow.  [Here's a very popular one from the Related questions sidebar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using PDO with prepared statements will take care of escaping your inputs :

```
$dsn  = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db_name";
try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, 'your_username', 'your_pass');
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
    die( "Erreur ! : " . $e->getMessage() );
 }

 $query  = "INSERT INTO mytable (firstname, lastname)
            VALUES (:firstname', :lastname)";
 $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);                          
 $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
 $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
 $stmt->execute();
```

Doc : [PHP Data Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Now use ODBC... :-) (See OP)

Comment: Topic starter don't know how prepare variables for safe SQL. You recommended PDO... This is like shot to small birds from tank.

Comment: @newman I think he should start from the right way. simplest things are not always best things.

Comment: Yes this is right way. But in some cases novice programmers just copy and past snippet and don't understand how it works, because all code is very hard. For education good start from simple ways and then understand all risks.

Comment: @newman: I definitely don't want to turn this into a discussion regarding what's best for novice programmers, but in my programming course, I teach my students to use prepared statements from day 1! (Be it a simple example...) And I do explain the risks involved when not using prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You could use replace to replace all ' with ''.  However, the proper way to do it is use parameterized queries where you pass your value to insert to the SQL Statement as a parameter. Then the language can clean up ' and any other characters/keywords that could cause an issue.  No matter the language, parameterized queries are the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). It's the best way to input user submitted data into a database. It makes sure the data is properly escaped automatically!

**phpdata.php**

```
<?php

function doInsert($firstname, $lastname) {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO mytable (firstname, lastname)
                VALUES (?, ?)";
    $pstmt = odbc_prepare($odb_con, $insert); /* Use global $odb_con to access the connection */
    $res = odbc_execute($pstmt, array($firstname, $lastname));
    return $res; /* Should return TRUE on success. */
}

?>
```

Do note that I haven't included any error checking in my code. Might be wise to implement that as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Looks almost identical to what I came up with from @FouadFodail answer (with ODBC). As for the error checking, yes I definitely do. I just tried to make a quick simple example to keep it short and sweet. Thanks again!

Answer (score -4):

You can try use function addslashes  for prepare data before insert.

I don't know how your work with database but this function is simple way for ask to your question.

[AddSlashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Comment: -1 Please don't suggest using addslashes.  It isn't the right function for escaping characters for SQL.

Comment: This is simple way for novice.

Comment: @newman It's also wrong to the point of dangerous, as it creates a false sense of security.